# What's the closest French equivalent to "I'm glad"?

Tags: demande-de-mot

The phrase "I'm glad" is an expression we often use in English, especially as a response, e.g. in response to a thank you note. What's the closest French equivalent to "I'm glad"?

I can think of a few possibilities. *Je suis heureux* is the first choice on Google Translate. But then there also is *Je suis content* and *Je m'amuse*.

What would you give as the closest equivalent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Je suis heureux* and *je suis content* are fine, but definitely not *je m'amuse* which would be very odd, kind of meaning you are making fun at the person you write to.

I would suggest:

> *je suis ravi que ça vous ait plu.*